# Meter tag with inverted values

Tags: html, css

I want to warn a user if a container is getting empty so i thought the `meter` tag would be good. But the meter tag changes color only if the amount is above the high and not below the low. Is there any chance I could tell it to change color when it gets low?

Sample code:

```
<p>He got a <meter low="69" high="80" max="100" value="89">B</meter> on the exam.</p>
```

Comment: If the value of the 'value' attribute is lees than the 'low' attribute - then it should change color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to swap the colors of high and low on the meter element - just switch the backgrounds of the pseudo-elements `meter::-webkit-meter-even-less-good-value` and `meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VS2ff/3/)**

### Where on earth did I get those properties from?

Well, first you need to edit the browser settings to show the Shadow DOM.

1) In developer tools - click settings:

[image]

2) Check the box: Show shadow DOM

[image]

2) Then inspect the DOM again and viola, all of the hidden internal elements of the meter are revealed and are able to be tweaked:

[image]

[image]

### Markup

```
<p>He got a <meter low="69" high="80" max="100" value="25">F</meter> on the exam.</p>

<p>He got a <meter low="69" high="80" max="100" value="76">C</meter> on the exam.</p>

<p>He got a <meter low="69" high="80" max="100" value="91">A</meter> on the exam.</p>
```

### CSS

```
meter::-webkit-meter-even-less-good-value {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgb(170, 221, 119)), color-stop(0.2, rgb(204, 238, 170)), color-stop(0.45, rgb(119, 170, 51)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(119, 170, 51)), to(rgb(170, 221, 119)));

}

meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgb(255, 119, 119)), color-stop(0.2, rgb(255, 204, 204)), color-stop(0.45, rgb(221, 68, 68)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(221, 68, 68)), to(rgb(255, 119, 119)));

}
```

**EDIT:**

I just noticed that there's a [css-tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/html5-meter-element/) on the meter element which explains (amongst other things) all of the default webkit styling

Comment: But it stays green. I want it to be red when below low and green when above low.

Comment: Oh so you want to swap the colors?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want

Comment: @Dharman - I updated my answer with a new fiddle which switches the colors and explains how to add further custom styling.

Comment: The article you gave me was perfect. I was looking for the `optimum` value. You're answer is good too but it does not work in all browsers.